# C# log4net multi purpose file logging

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, log4net

I'm building an application where I need to log different things such as application behaviour (opening/closing of windows, exceptions, warnings etc...) and data read/write (in csv format)
I've got this log4net.config file

```
<log4net>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="ApplicationLog" />
            <appender-ref ref="DigitalWriteLog" />
            <appender-ref ref="AnalogWriteLog" />
            <appender-ref ref="AnalogReadLog" />
        </root>
        <appender name="ApplicationLog" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
            <file value="Application.log" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
            <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="DigitalWriteLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
            <file value="DigitalWrite/" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <datePattern value="dd-MM-yyyy'.csv'" />
            <staticLogFileName value="false" />
            <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Date" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="AnalogWriteLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
            <file value="AnalogWrite/" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <datePattern value="dd-MM-yyyy'.csv'" />
            <staticLogFileName value="false" />
            <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Date" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="AnalogReadLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
            <file value="AnalogRead/" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <datePattern value="dd-MM-yyyy'.csv'" />
            <staticLogFileName value="false" />
            <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Date" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </log4net>
```

and I use this code to instantiate the logs

```
    private static readonly ILog applicationLog = LogManager.GetLogger("ApplicationLog");
    private static readonly ILog digitalWriteLog = LogManager.GetLogger("DigitalWriteLog");
    private static readonly ILog analogWriteLog = LogManager.GetLogger("AnalogWriteLog");
    private static readonly ILog analogReadLog = LogManager.GetLogger("AnalogReadLog");
```

and use it like this

```
    applicationLog.Info("Some info");
    digitalWriteLog(String.Format("Some digital write csv"));
    analogWriteLog(String.Format("Some analog write csv"));
    digitalReadLog(String.Format("Some analog read csv"))
```

but as I go check the .csv files they have the complete log and not separate messagges.

```
        =============  Started Logging  =============        
Opening main window
Entering manual mode
15:49:56,6,250,1.575,000,700,000,700,000,562,500,1.409,335,1.480,509
Starting manual mode
15:50:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
15:50:00,0,004,0,004,0,004,0,004
15:50:01,6,250,1.575,000,700,000,700,000,562,500,1.414,851,1.485,777
15:50:01,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
15:50:02,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
15:50:03,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0
Ending manual mode
15:50:05,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
15:50:05,0,004,0,004,0,004,0,004
15:50:06,6,250,1.575,000,700,000,700,000,562,500,1.420,350,1.491,026
Closing main window
        =============  Ended Logging  =============
```

When it should be for the AnalogReadLog

```
15:49:56,6,250,1.575,000,700,000,700,000,562,500,1.409,335,1.480,509
15:50:01,6,250,1.575,000,700,000,700,000,562,500,1.414,851,1.485,777
15:50:06,6,250,1.575,000,700,000,700,000,562,500,1.420,350,1.491,026
```

Short recap: I need to log different things to different files.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace this

```
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="ApplicationLog" />
    <appender-ref ref="DigitalWriteLog" />
    <appender-ref ref="AnalogWriteLog" />
    <appender-ref ref="AnalogReadLog" />
</root>
```

with:

```
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="ApplicationLog" />
</root>
<logger additivity="false" name="DigitalWriteLog">
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="DigitalWriteLog" />
</logger>
<logger additivity="false" name="AnalogWriteLog">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="AnalogWriteLog" />
</logger>
<logger additivity="false" name="AnalogReadLog">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="AnalogReadLog" />
</logger>
```